# Ruby on Rails - Group posts and sum prices

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, select, grouping

In my application I have models `Visits` & `Post` &

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :visits
```

When a visitor visits a post, I am adding it to my `visits` table with `post_id` and `price` *(`price` is `decimal`)*.

In my dashboard, I want to show which posts they have viewed *(grouped)* and how much they have earned.

*For instance:*
**1)** post 1, viewed 54 times and earned $1.6, **2)** post 2, viewed 39 times and earned $1.1, etc

*I have tried with:*

```
- a = Visit.group(:post_id).where(user: current_user).sum(:price)
- a.each do |n|
  %p
    = n
```

This gives me, each `post_id`, but `price` is just * BigDecimal:7fb2625f9238,'0.15E1* & I can't find *post title* by doing `n.post.title` & `n.post.title` gives me error: `undefined method 'post'`

*This is result I get:*

```
[44, #<BigDecimal:7fb2625f9238,'0.15E1',18(36)>]

[45, #<BigDecimal:7fb2625f8dd8,'0.13E1',18(36)>]

[46, #<BigDecimal:7fb2625f8928,'0.3E-1',9(36)>]
```

I have also tried with:

```
- Visit.select([:post_id, :price]).where(user: current_user).each do |e|
  %p
    = e.post.title
    = e.cpc_bid
```

This option gives me all the posts and prices individually and not combined.

*Results are like:*

```
Post title 1, 0.15
Post title 1, 0.01
Post title 2, 0.1
Post title 1, 0.15
Post title 2, 0.1
Post title 2, 0.1
Post title 2, 0.1
Post title 1, 0.15
```

*I also tried with:*

```
- Visit.select([:post_id, :price]).group(:post_id).where(user: current_user).each do |e|
  %p
    = e.post.title
    = e.price
```

This option gives me only one of the visits on the post with its price.

*Results are:*

```
Post title 2, 0.1
Post title 1, 0.15
```

My last try was:

```
- Visit.joins(:post).group(:post_id).select('sum(price) as earnings', :post_id, :title, 'count(visits.id) as total_views').where(user: current_user).each do |e|
  %p
    = e.title
    = e.price
```

This gives me this error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "posts.title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...ECT sum(price) as earnings, "visits"."post_id", "title", c...
```

How can I combine them together with sum of `price` on all post, with its post title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @MikDiet works perfectly, only issue I had was that I was getting error from `PostgreSql`:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "posts.title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...ECT sum(price) as earnings, "visits"."post_id", "title", c...
```

and I changed it to:

```
Visit.joins(:post).group([:post_id, :title]).select('sum(cpc_bid) as earnings', :post_id, :title, 'count(visits.id) as total_views').where(influencer: current_user)
```

And it worked.

*NB: I couldn't find the answer without @MikDiet's help and all credits goes to him*

Answer (score 1):

You need to join tables and group

```
Post.joins(:visits).group(:id)
    .where(visits: { user_id: current_user.id})
    .select("*, sum(price) as total_price, count(visits.id) as total_views")
```

It adds to post instance accessors `total_price` and `total_views`.

Comment: Thanks @MikDiet. It works in my `Development ENV` where I have `sqlite3` as my database. In `Production ENV`, I use `PostgreSql` and I get this error: `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "visits.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` & shouldn't `sum(visits.id)` be `count(visits.id)`, since `sum` will sum all `ID`s and not count them?

Comment: And this will give me all posts and I only want to display posts that user has visited, thats why I had `where(user: current_user)`. Where can I add this? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Yes, I made a typo, there should be `count(visits.id)`

Comment: Updated with `current_user`